# I18n in Struts-menu with Struts 2

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2, menuitem

I've developed a menu using struts-menu 2.4.3 with Struts 2. It's working ok but I need to take the titles of the menus from a properties file (router-messages.properties). The whole application is internationalized like this. But it just doesn't work with struts-menu. Here is my menu-config.xml file:

```
<Menu name="mainMenu" title="" >
          <Item name="ecfMenu" title="ECFs" roles="FISCO" location="DisconnectedEcfsSearch" />
          <Item name="reportsMenu" title="Relatórios" roles="ADMIN" location="AlarmReportSearch"/>
          <Item name="fiscoMenu" title="Fisco" roles="ADMIN" location="UpdateFiscoForm"/>
          <Item name="alarmMenu" title="Alarmes" roles="ADMIN" location="AlarmNotification"/>
          <Item name="userMenu" title="application.header.users" roles="ADMIN" location="UserSearch"/>
          <Item name="consoleMenu" title="Console" roles="FISCO" location="ConsoleSearch"/>
        </Menu>
```

Please notice that I'm trying to use a key to my properties file in the item 'userMenu'. All other items work, but not this one.

Here's my jsp:

```
   <menu:useMenuDisplayer permissions="rolesAdapter" name="Velocity" 
       config="/WEB-INF/tabs.html">
       <menu:displayMenu name="mainMenu" />
    </menu:useMenuDisplayer>
```

I searched around and even found a guy with the same question but there was no response for him. =/

Does anybody know how to make struts-menu recognize that I'm using a key to a properties file and not a literal String??

Thanks!

Comment: Consider joining the STRUTS-USER Mailing List :  http://struts.apache.org/mail.html if you get an answer there first it would be interesting if you could post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**For the menu-config.xml:**

```
<Menu name="mainMenu" title="" >
       <Item name="userMenu" title="application.header.users" roles="ADMIN" location="UserSearch"/>
</Menu>
```

**For the JSP:**

Use this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="menu" uri="http://struts-menu.sf.net/tag-el"%>
```

Instead of this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="menu" uri="http://struts-menu.sf.net/tag"%>
```

**Invoking the menu:**

```
<menu:useMenuDisplayer bundle="messages" permissions="rolesAdapter" name="Velocity" 
       config="/WEB-INF/tabs.html">
       <menu:displayMenu name="mainMenu" />
</menu:useMenuDisplayer>
```

For the bundle="messages" provide the name of your resource bundle.

I hope it works for you!